# Difference between usePreviousDistinct with useEffect and without

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I needed a hook to get the previous distinct value of a specific state. It looks like this and it  seems to work:

```js
function usePreviousDistinct(state) {
  const prevRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    prevRef.current = state;
  }, [state]);

  return prevRef.current;
}
```

I've also seen there is a `usePreviousDistinct` hook in the [react-use package](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/usePreviousDistinct.ts) but the approach is different than mine.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useFirstMountState } from './useFirstMountState';

export type Predicate<T> = (prev: T | undefined, next: T) => boolean;

const strictEquals = <T>(prev: T | undefined, next: T) => prev === next;

export default function usePreviousDistinct<T>(value: T, compare: Predicate<T> = strictEquals): T | undefined {
  const prevRef = useRef<T>();
  const curRef = useRef<T>(value);
  const isFirstMount = useFirstMountState();

  if (!isFirstMount && !compare(curRef.current, value)) {
    prevRef.current = curRef.current;
    curRef.current = value;
  }

  return prevRef.current;
}
```

I wonder if I have not understood something or am missing something. Is my version also correct?

In my test I could not find a difference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-mayer-zpym8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

- `useEffect()` together with `useRef()` (your version) does **not** show the latest value.
- `useRef()` without `useEffect()` gives you the correct value, because it runs synchronously, but doesn't have the advantages that come with asynchronicity.
- `useEffect()` together with `useState()` gives you the correct value, but might trigger unnecessary renders (adds potentially unnecessary overhead).

Your version **looks like** it works as expected, because the *old value* that is shown is the one that you expect to see as the *new value*. But the *actual* new value is not the one you want.

#### Example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const MyComponent = function(props){
    const [state, setState ] = useState(0);

    return <React.Fragment>
        state: { state },<br />
        with useEffect: { usePreviousDistinctUE( state ) },<br />
        w/o useEffect: { usePreviousDistinctR( state ) },<br />

        <button onClick={ function(){
            setState( state + 1 );
        } }>
            increment
        </button>
    </React.Fragment>;
};

const usePreviousDistinctUE = function( value ){
    const prevRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        prevRef.current = value;
        console.log('with useEffect, prev:', prevRef.current, ', current:', value);
    }, [value]);

    return prevRef.current;
};

const usePreviousDistinctR = function( value ){
    const prevRef = useRef();
    const curRef = useRef( value );

    if( curRef.current !== value ){
        prevRef.current = curRef.current;
        curRef.current = value;
    }

    console.log('w/o useEffect, prev:', prevRef.current, ', current:', curRef.current);
    return prevRef.current;
};
```

The values shown on the page are the same, but in the console they are different. That means the value in the `useEffect()` version is changed, it is only not yet shown on the page.

If you just **add** another hook that updates **anything unrelated** (leaving everything else unchanged), then the page (might*) magically show the updated value again, because the page is re-rendered and the previously already changed value is shown. The value is now wrong in your eyes, but it is not *changed*, only *shown*:

```
// ...
    with useEffect: { usePreviousDistinctUE( state ) },<br />
    w/o useEffect: { usePreviousDistinctR( state ) },<br />
    anything updated: { useAnythingUpdating( state ) },<br />
// ...

const useAnythingUpdating = function(state){
    const [result, setResult ] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        setResult( state );
        console.log('anything updated');
    });
    return result;
};
```

*But you shouldn't rely on something else triggering a re-render. I'm not even sure this would update as expected under all circumstances.

#### more Details:

**`useEffect()`** is triggered at some time when react decides that the `prop` must have been changed. The `ref` is changed then, but react will not 'get informed' about a `ref` change, so it doesn't find it necessary to re-render the page to show the changed value.

In the example **without `useEffect()`** the change happens synchronously.
React doesn't 'know' about this change either, but (if everything else runs as expected) there will be always a re-render when necessary anyway (you will have called that function from another function that is rendered at the end).

(Not informing react about the change is basically the point in using `useRef()`: sometimes you want just a value, under your own control, without react doing magic things with it.)